# Set height of picker with react-native

Tags: ios, react-native, picker

I have a picker in my react-native ios app and want to set the height but the example won't honor flex, a style height or a height attribute.

```
<Picker
    style={[styles.testbox, {borderColor: '#00F', flex:1, height: 100}]}
    selectedValue={this.state.language}
    height={100}
    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({language: itemValue})}>
    <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
    <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
</Picker>
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There's no `height` prop per the docs, so you can remove that.

From playing around with the styling, it looks like the most important part is to set the `itemStyle` prop and define the `height` value there. You'll probably also want to style the `Picker` component itself and set the `height` value to be the same for the best looking results, but you don't *need* to do that.

Minimal Example:

```
<Picker style={{width: 200, height: 44}} itemStyle={{height: 44}}>
  <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
  <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
</Picker>
```

Here's a [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/HkM_BcGBW) showing a full example for varying heights (code copy pasted below):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Picker } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      language: 'haxe',
      firstLanguage: 'java',
      secondLanguage: 'js',
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Unstyled:</Text>
        <Picker
          style={[styles.picker]} itemStyle={styles.pickerItem}
          selectedValue={this.state.language}
          onValueChange={(itemValue) => this.setState({language: itemValue})}
        >
          <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
          <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
          <Picker.Item label="Python" value="python" />
          <Picker.Item label="Haxe" value="haxe" />
        </Picker>

        <Text style={styles.title}>Shows one row:</Text>
        <Picker
          style={[styles.onePicker]} itemStyle={styles.onePickerItem}
          selectedValue={this.state.firstLanguage}
          onValueChange={(itemValue) => this.setState({firstLanguage: itemValue})}
        >
          <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
          <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
          <Picker.Item label="Python" value="python" />
          <Picker.Item label="Haxe" value="haxe" />
        </Picker>

        <Text style={styles.title}>Shows above and below values:</Text>
        <Picker
          style={[styles.twoPickers]} itemStyle={styles.twoPickerItems}
          selectedValue={this.state.secondLanguage}
          onValueChange={(itemValue) => this.setState({secondLanguage: itemValue})}
        >
          <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
          <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
          <Picker.Item label="Python" value="python" />
          <Picker.Item label="Haxe" value="haxe" />
        </Picker>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginTop: 20,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  picker: {
    width: 200,
    backgroundColor: '#FFF0E0',
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
  pickerItem: {
    color: 'red'
  },
  onePicker: {
    width: 200,
    height: 44,
    backgroundColor: '#FFF0E0',
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
  onePickerItem: {
    height: 44,
    color: 'red'
  },
  twoPickers: {
    width: 200,
    height: 88,
    backgroundColor: '#FFF0E0',
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
  twoPickerItems: {
    height: 88,
    color: 'red'
  },
});
```

Comment: This works great, thanks! It's not at all what the documentation is saying... need to remember to read the source code instead.

Comment: NOTE: Does not apply to Android. `itemStyle` is only for iOS. Hopefully that saves time for others looking for a cross-platform solution.

Comment: For android, wrapping `<Picker/>` into a `<View/>` and giving that `<View/>`  height works for me.